# Go imageproxy inaccessible from docker container

Tags: macos, go, docker

I am trying to deploy the excellent Go image proxy server https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy on Mac OSX as docker container via Docker Cloud.

I cannot make the container accessible to my browser

`docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 willnorris/imageproxy:latest  /go/bin/imageproxy -addr 0.0.0.0:8080`

should expose the server at `docker-machine ip [vmname]`, in this case 192.168.56.100

I verified my setup by running a vanilla Express server in the same way.

Would anyone know what is up with the dockerization of this service? https://hub.docker.com/r/willnorris/imageproxy/

Comment: Copying the link from your comment on my (now) deleted answer:  Issue is filed in github here: https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/issues/57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From noogen https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/issues/57

Was able to reproduce this with the 'willnorris/imageproxy' version. I can curl port 8080 inside of the container but not from the host.

The default configuration binds to 127.0.0.1 (should be 0.0.0.0) because of this line: imageproxy (version HEAD) listening on localhost:8080

localhost in the imageproxy docker container (cat /etc/hosts) is map to 127.0.0.1

Change the Dockerfile line 8 to:
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/imageproxy", "-addr 0.0.0.0:8080"]